# Android AR Vuforia camera black live feed

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm new to Unity and was working on an AR remote to turn on some LEDs on an Arduino. Everything worked just fine, but by adding the 2nd scene, the AR camera no longer works and just shows a black screen.

I'm using the latest version of Unity and building for Android.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you marking the ARcamera as Dontdestroyonload?